# How to create dimname names to an already existing table?

Tags: r

In **R**, how can I create dimname names to an already existing tables?

Now I have a table as follow.

[image]

I would like to name each dimension by using dnn option
of table, such as

```
obs=as.table(obs,dnn=c("Math","Statistics"))
```

But the dimname names are not correctly named.

How do I create dimname names to a existing table?

**More information about this question.**

What I would like to know is how to create the names for each variable in the contingency table. That is, for example, the first dimension, I would name the variable "Math" which has two rows "dislike" and "like". And then, for the second dimension, I would name the variable "Statistics" which has two columns "dislike" and "like"

So I would like the table to look as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a toy example:

```
obs <- table(gl(2,2), gl(2,2))
#    1 2
#  1 2 0
#  2 0 2

dimnames(obs) <- list(c("Math","Statistics‌​"), c("Math","Statistics‌​"))
#           Math Statistics‌​
#Math          2          0
#Statistics‌​    0          2
```

---

You can't use `as.table` to achieve what you want, because:

```
> as.table.default
function (x, ...) 
{
    if (is.table(x)) 
        return(x)
....
```

Your `obs` is readily a table, so `as.table` does nothing but return it straight away.

---

> Maybe I should have explained this better. What I would like to know is how to create the names for each variable in the contingency table. That is, for example, the first dimension, I would name the variable "Math" which has two rows "dislike" and "like". And then, for the second dimension, I would name the variable "Statistics" which has two columns "dislike" and "like".

Then you need a named list:

```
dimnames(obs) <- list(Math = c("dislike", "like"), Statistics = c("dislike", "like"))

#          Statistics
#Math      dislike like
#  dislike       2    0
#  like          0    2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it the following way:
obs=as.table(obs,dnn=list("Math","Statistics"))
Use 'list' instead of 'c'.

Comment: Maybe I should have explained this better. What I would like to know is how to create the names for each variable in the contingency table. That is, for example, the first dimension, I would name the variable "Math" which has two rows "dislike" and "like". And then, for the second dimension, I would name the variable "Statistics" which has two columns "dislike" and "like".